# Disposing DBContext then attaching entities to new instance with EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an application that needs to synchronize in-memory data with a remote database at an hourly interval. So the data gets pulled from the database at application launch and the DbContext is disposed.

```
List<Department> Departments;
using (var context = new CompanyContext())
{
    this.Departments = context.Departments.Include("Employees").AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

Another thread launches a synchronization function after an hour. I can confirm that there **HAVE** been changes made to the `[this.Departments]` collection (which is shared by all threads).

```
bool changesDetectedAndSaved = false;
using (var context = new CompanyContext())
{
    foreach (var department in this.Departments)
    {
        foreach (var employee in department.Employees)
        {
            context.Departments.Attach(employee);
        }

        context.Departments.Attach(departments);
    }

    // Always returns false.
    context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    changesDetectedAndSaved = context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());
    if (changesDetectedAndSaved) { context.SaveChanges(); }
}
Console.WriteLine("Saved: {0}.", changesDetectedAndSaved);
```

The `[context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()]` method **ALWAYS** returns false. It is not possible to keep the `DbContext` alive for this long since the database is remote. Isn't `DbSet<TEntity>.Attach(entity)` supposed to handle exactly this kind of thing?

**Please Note**: This is not a threading issue as I get the same results when the code is put into a single context such as [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/entity-framework-gotchas/).

Comment: have you deleted your old question? that was mostly the same issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes I have. It was exactly the same issue and it did not make sense to keep both questions active. The only answer I got there seemed to indicate that it was not possible to re-attach once a context has been disposed.

Comment: ah, ok, I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `DbContext` to track changes during that hour; attaching an entity to a `DbContext` is instructing the `DbContext` instance to track said entity.  When you attach an entity object to a new `DbContext`, it will attach as `Unchanged` and nothing will happen with it when you call `SaveChanges()`.

To have the entity updated in the database, you must set its state to `Modified`.  Easiest way to attach and set the state is as follows:

```
context.Entry( employee ).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

[Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Prior to Entity Framework 5 there were T4 templates for self-tracking entities ([which are still available for use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613924)) where entity objects themselves could keep track of their state, but those are no longer recommended for use.

Comment: Thanks. That means I will have to maintain a cache of modified entries myself. Makes sense. I am also assuming from your answer that if I run the 'pull' query again while keeping the context alive and attach these disconnected entries, that would not make sense as well. EF will probably treat them as new entries rather than modified.

Comment: attaching as unchanged wouldn't do anything; attaching as added would generate a duplicate PK error; attaching as modified could result in two entities updating the same DB record

Comment: Thanks again. Ended up creating a simple thread-safe entity tracker and disabled user interaction during synchronization.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks. My scenario was rather simple so a `Dictionary<TPrimaryKey, State>` served the purpose. However, thank you for that link. It would be helpful going forward.